# A question about the commutator $[J^s,u]\partial_x u$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

I am studying the use of the commutator for finding the estimate of energy. During my looking through many papers I found that [this paper](https://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcds.2019145) contains a possible typo. [Here is the archive version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02027) which has the same prospective typo!

Another question about the commutator. When I espand the follawing commutator $[J^s,u]\partial_x u$ the last two terms are cancel eachohter! Are my calculations right?

\begin{align}
[J^s,u]\partial_x u &= J^s(u\, \partial_x u)- u J^s(\partial_x u)\\
&=J^s(u) \partial_x u + u J^s(\partial_x u) - u J^s(\partial_x u)\\
&=J^s(u) \partial_x u 
\end{align}

Is the above right?

Comment: If $s=2k$ is an even integer, then $J^s=(1-\Delta)^k$. Check your computation in this case. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation is not right in general. $J^s$ does not satisfy the Leibniz rule. The idea is that at least one of the derivatives hits the function $w$ in the paper, So the authors used the commutator to get rid of it.